# Passing value to a function in recursion in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have been trying to pass value from my recursive helper function to the parent, but it is passing `None`. I am learning Python and recursion and trying to understand how the values are passed between functions.

```
def superDigitSum(n,k):
    num2str = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))*k] #creates the list[1,4,8,1,4,8,1,4,8]
    result=0
    return superDigitSumHelper(num2str, result)

def superDigitSumHelper(num2str, helper_result):
    if not num2str :
        return helper_result
    else:
        helper_result+=num2str[-1]
        superDigitSumHelper(num2str[:-1],helper_result)

print(superDigitSum(148,3))
```

The code creates the list [1,4,8,1,4,8,1,4,8] and sums the values.  I expect the result to be `39` (3 * (1+4+8)).

Comment: If you have an answer which suits your needs, please dont forget to mark it as such for people to later use as a point of reference. :)

Comment: Python programmers use `snake_case` instead of `lowerCamelCase`. You should name your function `super_digit_sum` instead of `superDigitSum`.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
else:
    helper_result+=num2str[-1]
    return superDigitSumHelper(num2str[:-1],helper_result)
```

Without returning the results of the recursive call you are just returning None

Answer (score 1):

Your function is slightly wrong.

You need to add a return the following to your *superDigitSumHelper* function:

```
return superDigitSumHelper(num2str[:-1], helper_result)
```

in your else conditional.

Essentially, it is returning none because after the function ends, it isnt returning anything so the default value is none.

Answer (score 1):

This clause returns `None` to the next call up the stack.  You need to return the last value:

```
else:
    helper_result+=num2str[-1]
    superDigitSumHelper(num2str[:-1],helper_result)
```

Instead,

```
else:
    helper_result+=num2str[-1]
    return superDigitSumHelper(num2str[:-1],helper_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to do things like `str(n)` or `list*k`, or even `*` at all, it kind of defeats the purpose of the exercise

```
def super_digit_sum (n, k):
  return sum (map (int, list (str (n)))) * k

print (super_digit_sum (148, 3)) # 39
```

But I'm sure the point of this is to use *primitive* features and operations as a means of learning how to write simple recursive programs...

---

We start with a simple function that sums the digits of a single input number

```
def sum_digits (n):
  if n < 10:
    return n
  else:
    return n % 10 + sum_digits (n // 10)

print (sum_digits (148))
# 13
```

Then we make a simple function that can multiply two numbers

```
def mult (n, m):
  if n is 0:
    return 0
  else:
    return m + mult (n - 1, m)

print (mult (3, 7))
# 21
```

Then combining the two, we write your main function

```
def super_digit_sum (n, k):
  return mult (sum_digits (n), k)

print (super_digit_sum (148, 3))
# 39
```

If you're allowed to use `*`, you can skip `mult` altogether and simply write

```
def super_digit_sum (n, k):
  return sum_digits (n) * k

print (super_digit_sum (148, 3))
# 39
```

This is a better program because you arrive at the answer in a straightforward manner. Compare that to the other approach of taking a number, converting it into a string, chopping it up into single characters, converting those characters back to digits, then summing the digits, and finally multiplying the result by a constant.

Both approaches arrive at the same result, but only one results in a program worth reading, imo. I talk about this roundabout-style of programming in another python Q&A: [How to count neighbors in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49680736/633183) I think you will find it helpful.

Comment: Sure thing. I will do my best to use primitive features to solve the exercises. :)